# ssl apache vhost working only in firefox

Tags: apache, ssl, browser, virtualhost, vhosts

I created a self signed ssl vhost for testing purpose.
this vhost is working perfectly on mozilla firefox but not working in all other browsers.
this is the vhost:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName mysubdomain.domain.tld
ServerAlias mysubdomain.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /my/own/ssl_test/
<Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
            AllowOverride ALL
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  What behaviour do you see in which other browsers?

Comment: here is the link  https://vds2584.sivit.org

Comment: i used this tuorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-12-04 to make the ssl vhost

Answer (score 0):

The certificate does not have a Common Name. Maybe that is why Chrome doesn't like it.

Compare:

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect vds2584.sivit.org:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep Subject.*CN
```

to:

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep Subject.*CN
        Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc, CN=*.google.com
```